# Magento2 how to programmatically pass customizable options when adding product to cart

Tags: magento2

Magento2.3.3 I am adding product to cart programmatically, how can I pass product customizable options together?

Answer (score 0):

> Please check below code, I hope it will be workfull for you.

```
  <?php
  namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\YourcontrollerName;
  use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;
      
  class YourcontrollerName extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
  { 
         protected $checkoutSession;
         protected $serializer;
         protected $cart;

        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        SerializerInterface $serializer,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart

        ) {
            $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
            $this->serializer = $serializer;
            $this->cart = $cart;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }
        
        
        public function execute() {
 
            $customOptions =    [
                        "option_id" => $optionId, // assign option Id
                        "option_value" => $optionTypeTitle // here set selected option item Id
                    ];

             $params = array(
               'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
               'product_id' => $productId, //product Id
               'qty'   => 1 //quantity of product                
             ); 

            $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);

            $productItem = $this->getProductQuote($_product);
            $productItem->setAdditionalData($this->serializer->serialize($customOptions));
            $productItem->setCustomPrice($productPrice);
            $productItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($productPrice);
            $productItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            $this->cart->save();
        }
    
    
        protected function getProductQuote($product){
            $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();        
            $cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);        
            return $cartItems;
        }
    
}
```

Comment: From the following what am I suppose to pass in $optionTypeTitle?
label: "test"
option_id: "2"
option_type: "checkbox"
print_value: "test"
value: "test"

Comment: "option_value" => $optionTypeTitle means label and "option_id" => $optionId means your option id. If you print your product custom options then you will find it.

Comment: I always get error 'The product's required option(s) weren't entered. Make sure the options are entered and try again.'

Comment: make sure you are not passign $params = array(
            'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
            'product_id' => $product_id, //product Id
            'qty'   => 1 //quantity of product,         'options' => [
        '1' => '5',
    ],       
            );

Comment: don't pass  'options' => [ '1' => '5', ] like this. Try now.

Comment: I am passing like this $params = [
    'form_Key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
    'product' => $productId,
    'qty' => '1',
    'options' => [
        2 => 3,
    ],
];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109775/discussion-between-hitesh-balpande-and-arjun).

Comment: Is the option checkbox. I have checkbox value to pass